# How to upgrade spatie/laravel-permission V1 to V2

Tags: php, laravel, upgrade, laravel-permission

On the second version of the database structure and the library is different. how to make an update without breaking anything?

[spatie/laravel-permission](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission#installation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are Upgrade instructions in the documentation:
https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission#upgrading

Comment: What part of it isn't working? Please be more specific.

Comment: d'not working migration: // Drop V1 foreign key constraints

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1091 Can't DROP 'role_has_permissions_permission_id_foreign'; check that column/key exists (SQL: alter table `role_has_permissions_v1` drop foreign key `role_has_permissions_pe  
  rmission_id_foreign`)